# Переадресация в папку PHP

Tags: php

Для переадресации использую на сайте `header("Location: /auth/")`.

Переместил скрипт в директорию, при срабатывании вышеуказанной команды перекидывает на главную. Как сделать так, чтобы осталась конструкция выше, но переадресовывало в `/папка/auth/`?

Comment: @Lektor, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используй `.htaccess`, чтобы при запросе `/auth/$1` открывалась `/папка/auth/$1`
Исправления нужно будет внести только в файле `.htaccess`

**Обновление**

Думаю, как-то так:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^auth/(.*)$ /newfolder/auth/$1[L]
```

Подробнее http://www.htaccess.net.ru/doc/mod_rewrite/index.php

Comment: @Get класс, вы не могли бы привести пример?

Comment: Обновил ответ

Answer (score 3):

```
header("Location: /папка/auth/")
```

upd: инструкция

1. Берем notepad++, открываем все документы, в которых содержится строка для замены.
2. Выделяем строку для замены, нажимаем `Ctrl + H`.
3. Вписываем, на что меняем, и нажимаем `Заменить всё во всех открытых документах`.
4. Радуемся профиту :)

Comment: @rnddev это понятно, интересует решение без изменения кода. Т.к придется по всем проекте менять.

Comment: @Lektor в редакторах уже давно есть массовая замена :)